# cursor index out of bounds "index 0 requested: with size 0"

Tags: android

I am getting cursor index out of bounds "index 0 requested: with size 0" error when I search my database for something. The item I am searching for in my database does not exist currently and i am aware of that but how do i handle a query where the item does not exist.

i send in a phone number

```
public String searchNumber(Context context,String number){

    ContactDB db = new ContactDB(context);
    db.open();
    Cursor curs = db.getIdFromPhone(number);
    String test = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(db.PHONE_NUMBER)); //fails here
    curs.close();
    db.close();
    return test;
}
```

query

```
public Cursor getIdFromPhone(String where){
    Cursor cur = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER}
    , PHONE_NUMBER + "='" + where + "'",null,null,null,null);
    if(cur != null)
        cur.moveToFirst();

    return cur;
}
```

test search

```
from = messages.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
String dbNumber = searchNumber(arg0,from);
            if(dbNumber.equals(from)){
      //do stuff
}else{
   //do other stuff
}
```

if number is not found it should do the else statement but it does not get that far

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false if the `Cursor` is empty. The returned `Cursor` from the `query()` call will never be null but it might be empty. You are never checking if the cursor is empty.

```
public String searchNumber(Context context,String number){

    ContactDB db = new ContactDB(context);
    db.open();
    Cursor curs = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER}
        , PHONE_NUMBER + "='" + number + "'",null,null,null,null);
    String test = null;
    if(curs.moveToFirst()) { //edit
        test = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(db.PHONE_NUMBER)); //fails here
    }
    curs.close();
    db.close();
    return test; // this will be null if the cursor is empty
}
```

And get rid of the `getIdFromPhone()` method.

Comment: pond i cant get rid of getIDFromPhone because i cant access query unless i am inside the database class which is what that method does. also i get a null pointer exception doing it your way. would it be any easier switching to boolean since all i need to know if the number exists in the database or not

Comment: Awesome, thanks Robby, that was super useful, was getting the same cur==null issue! :)

Answer (score 5):

While you retrive value you have to use `cursor.moveToNext;`

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```