# Sqlite query returns mRowIdColumnIndex of -1

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to check if there is already a value in one of my DB columns so I've written this code to do so:

```
             public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException {

 Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
      {KEY_TOTAL_HOURS, KEY_TOTAL_MINUTES}, KEY_ROWID +"=" + rowId, null, null, null, null);{

     mCursor.moveToFirst();
     return mCursor;
 }
 }
```

But the cursor I'm getting back gives

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316336/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-index-0-requested-with-size-0

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of [moveToFirst](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) to make sure there is a valid row returned: it will return false if there is not. It appears there is no row with the id you've specified.

Comment: it returns something else. what can be the problem?

Comment: Something else? Is `moveToFirst` *true* or *false*?

Comment: I cant seem to find its value in the debugger.