# what EXACTLY does index 0 requested with a size of 0 means?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm getting this error in my application. I just want to know what does this error exaclty means. It would be really good if you give a simple example to explain

Comment: How do you get the error, please provide some code and elaborate your question.

Comment: The very first result from Google is [this (solved) Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316336/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-index-0-requested-with-size-0).

Comment: If one of the answers you got solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 5):

it just means your Array or Cursor or what ever is not having any elements, its length is 0. so

assume

```
String[] s = {};//not sure if it compiles. just an example for understanding
s[0]//doing this means asking for 1st elemnt when s does't have any..
```

Answer (score 4):

You are asking for the first element of an empty array. There is no first element, so you get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code (which would be very helpful here), it sounds like you've got an empty array or list, and you're asking for the first element (which doesn't exist).  For example:

```
String[] anArray = {"Hello", "world"}; //An array with two elements
System.out.println(anArray[0]); //prints "Hello".  anArray[0] gets the first element.

String[] anotherArray = {};  //An empty array.  There's nothing here to get.
System.out.println(anotherArray[0]);  //throws an exception because there's no first element to get.
```

I think the same thing probably happens with `ArrayList` and other container classes, but I don't remember offhand.  I hope that's EXACTLY what you were looking for.